# .exe is not a valid Win32 application?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, desktop-computer

So, I don't know what has happened to my computer but I can't access some of the programs. I can't open `cmd` via administrator, wampserver, etc. I can't even change the time; it says

> I don't have permission to perform this task -- Please contact computer admin for help.

Before this all happened, I kept on restarting my PC and letting it repair because it's has been  slow and lagging at times.

Comment: Which is your OS ?

Comment: my os is win7...

Comment: What do you meant by 'kept on restarting my pc' ?

Comment: sometimes my pc freezes for a long time, so I would just restart it. Then theres this repair and continue that pops up after rebooting and I sometimes choose the repair hoping it could help. Then all of the sudden, after it is done repairing and already in the background, when I try to open some apps the problem pops up. Also, I could not change my time anymore and wont let me access to cmd cuz   it says that I need access from admin even though I am the admin.

Comment: To repair a slow/laggy PC many good softwares are available. You should try one of that. To solve the current problems do a system restore.

Comment: Random freezes could be caused by a whole range of issues, both hardware and software. Without any further troubleshooting into what caused the freezing in the first place, I doubt it will be easy/possible to diagnose the resultant problems you're having now. I'd recommend testing your __hard drive__ (`badblocks -svn`), __RAM__ (memtest86+), __CPU__ and __GPU__ (games/benchmark tools) from a Linux live drive to begin to rule out hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with fdsfgdsdf.

If it were data corruption only a few files would stop working. In your case even system files are not working.

The slowlyness would suggest you are having spyware on your computer.

I would recommend going to http://www.surfright.nl/en/ and download `Hitman pro kickstart`.

You can install this to an empty USB Disk (it will clear all content). Then you can boot from the USB drive to scan your computer. An active internet connection is required for the latest definitions to be downloaded prior to the scan.

Comment: I finally got it, I just changed my user account access via safe mode cuz it restrics me here. Thank btw.